# Creation of columns based on date column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-12-01', periods=3, freq='D')
dfd = pd.DataFrame({ "ID" :["11", "10", "15"],
                    'Date': rng, 
                    'status': ['active', 'active', 'finished'] })
```

And I need to add 2 columns:

1. Col1 = If this ID had previously "active" status give 1 else 0
2. Col2 = If this ID had IN THE LAST 12 MONTHS "active" status give 1 else 0

To be more precision below I giv results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare values of `active` for boolean mask, for second compare previous year by [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) with greater like `now - 1year` it means from `2019-12-15` to `2020-12-15` if test today:

```
m = dfd['status'].eq('active')
m1 = dfd['Date'].gt(pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.DateOffset(years=1))
dfd['Col1'] = m.astype(int)
dfd['Col2'] = (m & m1).astype(int)

print (dfd)
   ID       Date    status  Col1  Col2
0  11 2015-12-01    active     1     0
1  10 2015-12-02    active     1     0
2  15 2015-12-03  finished     0     0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.DateOffset(years=1))
2019-12-15 09:10:19.888687
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines of code:

```
dfd['Col1'] = dfd['status'].map({'active': 1, 'finished': 0})
dfd['Col2'] = dfd['Date'].gt(pd.to_datetime('now') - np.timedelta64(12, 'M')).astype(int)
```

The first line does the `Col1`, the second does the `Col2`.

**Edited:**

@rumor154 asked me to show an example with the `Col2` being one:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=3, freq='D')
dfd = pd.DataFrame({ "ID" :["11", "10", "15"],
                    'Date': rng, 
                    'status': ['active', 'active', 'finished'] }) 

dfd['Col1'] = dfd['status'].map({'active': 1, 'finished': 0})
dfd['Col2'] = dfd['Date'].gt(pd.to_datetime('now') - np.timedelta64(12, 'M')).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
        Date  ID    status  Col1  Col2
0 2020-01-01  11    active     1     1
1 2020-01-02  10    active     1     1
2 2020-01-03  15  finished     0     1
```

Comment: How works code for col2 ? I do not understand? In which situation it will be 1?

Comment: @rumor154 When the date is after the date 12 months ago

Comment: Ok but you do not take into consideration that only 'active' status is important for us